# Feature request: use Ctrl-RightArrow/Ctrl-LeftArrow to navigate between pages

Tags: feature-request, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

http://habrahabr.ru/, for example, uses Ctrl-RightArrow to go to previous page and Ctrl-LeftArrow to go to next page. It's a very convenient way to navigate and supposed to be an easy change.

Clarification, it's not about back and forward browser buttons, it's about going from for example

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?page=**2**&tab=newest + CtrlRightArrow = 
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?page=**3**&tab=newest

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?page=**2**&tab=newest + CtrlLeftArrow = 
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?page=**1**&tab=newest

Comment: Opera have that option built-in for most of the web sites.

Comment: Also why bother with Ctrl at all? I can't think of any reasons why using just the arrows would cause issues.

Comment: Isn't this browser-specific? IE has done this for a long time.

Comment: @Changeling, just to be sure: the question is not about moving backwards in the browser's history (and then forward again if applicable). Instead, it's about moving, for example, to the next page with answers, if pagination is active. (Well, that is what I understand...)

Comment: Ah ok.. did not make sense until your explanation

Answer (score 2):

If implemented, then rather than having a site define keyboard shortcuts, I'd use [standard relationships](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links) in `<link>` or `<a>` instead. Then it's up to the browser to handle it. For example:

```
<head>
  :
  <link rel="start" href="/questions/39053">
  <link rel="next" href="/questions/39053?tab=oldest&page=2#tab-top">
  :
</head>
```

Or, just like the Stack Overflow sites already do:

```
<a href="/questions/7322?tab=oldest&amp;page=2#tab-top" title="go to page 2" 
  rel="next"><span class="page-numbers next"> next</span></a>
```